# Extract properties from an array of objects and create new array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have the following array of objects

```
let cars = [
  {
    "color": "purple",
    "info":{
      "name": 'new name'
    }
  },
  {
    "color": "red",
     "info":{
      "name": 'new name 1'
    }
  },
  {
    "color": "red",
     "info":{
      "name": 'new name 1'
    }
  },
  {
    "color": "red",
     "info":{
      "name": 'new name 2'
    }
  },
]
```

I want to map to this cars array and extract the value of `cars.info.name` and create a new array like this:

```
[
{"result": 'new name'},
{"result": 'new name 1'},
{"result: 'new name 2'},
]
```

Does anybody know how to achieve this in Javascript. I have been thinking but couldn't come up with some ways to handle it.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? _"I want to map to this cars array"_ seems like a good start.

Comment: `cars.map((x)=>({result : x.info.name}))` ??

Comment: `let results = cars.map(car => { return {"result": car.info.name}})`

Comment: using map I can do like this but it returns all the name elements. I want to avoid extracting the duplicates info name for example in the data: I have two same value for name: new name 1, I want to extract only one from there, just like the new array in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) methods.

Read documentation for more info.

Basically use `filter` to remove duplicates first, then `map` to iterate thru the array and create a new array with just the `info.name` value

```js
let cars = [
  {
    "color": "purple",
    "info":{
      "name": 'new name'
    }
  },
  {
    "color": "red",
     "info":{
      "name": 'new name 1'
    }
  },
  {
    "color": "red",
     "info":{
      "name": 'new name 1'
    }
  },
  {
    "color": "red",
     "info":{
      "name": 'new name 2'
    }
  },
]


//edit: remove duplicates in 1 line
const res = cars.filter((v,i,a)=>a.findIndex(v2=>(v2.info.name===v.info.name))===i).map(x => ({ result: x.info.name}))


console.log(res);
```

Comment: Hey it returns the new name 1 twice but I would like to return it only once

Comment: thats becuz you have 2 objects with that same value in your array. There are other methods if you want to filter that. Let me edit my answer

Comment: Yeah this where I actually stucked, need to filter our the same result values and extract only one in case they are similar

Comment: @ninja sorry took me some time to edit my answer, I was busy with something else, please check it out

Comment: Lokks like it's working thanks